# Install MinGW 64bit For Use With Kivy - Unzipped file does not contain “bin” folder with “gcc.exe”

Tags: python, gcc, windows-7-x64, kivy, mingw-w64

I am following these instructions -- https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Creating-a-64-bit-development-environment-with-MinGW-on-Windows -- to get Kivy to work with the python 2.7.6 install I already have on my windows 7 laptop.

In the github it says there should be the following folders after you extract the zip file:

C:\dev-64\mingw64\bin C:\dev-64\mingw64\include C:\dev-64\mingw64\mingw ...

However, those folders don't exist when I unzip. Here is a screenshot of my unzip - http://i62.tinypic.com/2u5s11w.jpg

Not sure what is up here, but there needs to be a "bin" folder with the gcc.exe inside.

One important note is that I created the "dev-64" folder myself. Although, I am not sure if that is supposed to be a program rather than a folder I simply created?

Comment: You have gotton ahold of the wrong zip file. If you downloaded x86_64-4.8.2-release-win32-sjlj-rt_v3-rev2.7z from the link in the github guide (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.8.2/threads-win32/sjlj/) it should have the correct structure. What you have is the mingw source, not their compiled binaries. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! Now I am on step 2 of the instructions from that github page. It is another link to sourceforge http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Extension/gendef/gendef-1.0.1346/ -- I actually downloaded the `mingw-get-setup.exe (86.5 kB)` and executed it in `mingw64/bin`. Do you know if I downloaded the right thing this time?!

Comment: For gendef, you need the gendef-1.0.1346-1-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma file. Don't use the mingw-get-setup.exe because that'll probably install different things in different places. You can extract the tar.lzma file with 7-zip.

Comment: oopsy, I already run that .exe :-(

Comment: You might want to uninstall. That installs 32-bit mingw not 64-bit.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what I have done since I executed in the `ming64/bin` folder. It doesn't show in my list of installed programs, so I can't uninstall from there. If I go to all programs through the start menu, then I do have MinGW Installation Manager, which I have open, and there does not appear to be any files installed - Just the option to install all sorts of files. So I am thinking that I have just downloaded the "Installation Manager" and nothing else.

Comment: Not sure, maybe delete that folder and start again?

Comment: Thanks for this help Matt. It has been a little over my head so far! So deleted `ming64` folder and started over. I know have the gendef.exe in my `ming64\bin` folder too.

Comment: I am now on step 3 of the github page, and I surprise surprise I am still unsure what to do. I have opened up the kivy.bat file, and there are two lines: `ECHO Setting Environment Variables:
ECHO #################################`. Am I supposed to put a pathway where all the hash tags are, is that what the instructions are getting at?

Comment: You should see in the bat file where it says something like set PATH=%kivy_portable_root%;%kivy_portable_root%Python;... Change it to e.g. PATH=%kivy_portable_root%;mingw64bin;%kivy_portable_root%Python;... where ming64bin is the full path to the bin directory in the mingw64 folder. You also have to make sure that all the python paths are pointing to where the 64 bit python is.

Comment: Why are you using the 64-bit python, btw? The kivy distribution comes with its own 32 bit python which should work just as well and out of the box.

Comment: I am wishing I just went with KIVY out of the box now. The reason I went this route is that that on the installations instructions page - http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#other-environments -- there is the option to work with an existing installation of python. And since I had python already installed with setuptools, numpy and nltk, I figure I would stick with what I got. I didn't know I was getting a little over my head however!

Answer (score 0):

I too had the very same issue (not with the zip but with getting 64 bit mingw for kivy) i used [tdm-gcc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/?source=dlp). I also found windows installers for [cython](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython) and [kivy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy) along with the [glew](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/) dlls that should get you all setup with kivys dependencies. This works fine for me on py 2.7.6 windows 7 and AMD64